# Golang binary only runs in powershell, not cmd, system error 67 has occurred

Tags: powershell, go, cmd

i installed go. When running it from cmd i receive an error:
[image]

When running in powershell inside the jetbrains intellij idea everything works.
[image]

Somone has an idea why?

Comment: Do `echo %PATH%` in both shells, and see what installations of Go they list. Do they differ? Correction: looks like it should be `$Env:Path` or someting like this in PS.

Comment: Aso, if you're going to try to compare between the two, you should at least have run both using the same working/current directory.

Comment: @kostix Both cmd and ps show `C:\go1.20.6\bin;` inside the output. Running it in a seperate ps os window still does not work

Comment: @kostix Although Goland-ps also shows two old installation directories (tried reinstalling in different folders) it still uses the binary previously mentioned

Comment: OK, that's really interesting, then. Care to also compare the outputs of `go env` run in both environments (where it works and where it doesn't)? (Please note that shells in Windows do support copying and pasting text (even `cmd.exe`), use that, [do not post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/720999)). I wonder if it's that some setting such as `GOPROXY` kicks in or some sort of A/V software intervenes making networking requests fail (on the other hand, `go version` does not need to hit the network). No more ideas at this point; need more info.

Comment: wow yes this also seems to happen for a friend. we both run windows 11 and think its a really strange problem. Since I have a docker compose setup for our project this doesnt really comcern me although it is a funny thing

Comment: Will try out your approaches tho! ty!

Comment: My German is far from perfect but I think I was able to correctly interpret the error from the first pic which basically says that some network name was not found. It's puzzling, so that's what worth investigating ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended to use gvm to install golang.
you also install other version with it.
https://github.com/moovweb/gvm